# how to integrate Libcurl on Qt5 C++ to consume resources from Azure cognitive

Tags: c++, azure, qt5, libcurl

Am creating an Application mandatory on C++ QT5, this app must use Azure Cognitive resources. But those resources just have an example on C# and JS

Making some research I found the LibCurl could be useful, but I got some implementation errors and references.

I already use PY with C++ (Cython), but the language is more difficult to understand. I use JS and C++ with no success. And finally, I try with an executable compiled already which, but not receive parameters because, is compiled already.

Reference: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL* mate = curl_easy_init();
if (mate) {
    CURLcode res;

    curl_easy_setopt(mate, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_easy_setopt(mate, CURLOPT_URL, "https://qnamate.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/generateAnswer");


    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "postman-token: xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "cache-control: no-cache");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "content-type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "authorization: EndpointKey xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx");

    curl_easy_setopt(mate, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    //json::Value frase:
    //frase["question"] = argv[1];

    char frase[] = "{\"question\":\"Hola\"}";
    curl_easy_setopt(mate, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, frase);

    res = curl_easy_perform(mate);
    curl_easy_cleanup(mate);

}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

I expected to send a phrase, convert this to JSON, send it to Azure via HTTP request and get an answer.

the regular error I get is

> error lnk2019 __imp__curl_easy_init

For the lib references, I follow all the steps for solving this on the community and still get the same error.

Comment: Why not use [Qt Network](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html#)?

Comment: Did you configure your project to point and link with libcurl.a?